# session variables are not persisting in php in another page

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `dbname`.`table`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 DAY
COMMENT 'Auto Delete Records'
DO
    BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `dbname`.`table` WHERE `Created_Date` < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    END

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near '' at line 6
```

can anyone please help in this

Comment: The code you have shown, has nothing to do with SESSIONS

Comment: The code you show does not actually make any sence! If a table does not exist create an event to delete something from the NON EXISTANT Table.????? Stop and have a quick think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a simple syntax error, you are using a `database`. `tablename` as the name of this Event, instead use a arbitrary name for your event.

```
delimiter :
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS tidy_session_table
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 DAY
COMMENT 'Auto Delete Old Session Records'
DO
    BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `dbname`.`table` WHERE `Created_Date` < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    END

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Also, did you have a `DELIMITER` statement?

Comment: @RickJames Good point

Answer (score -3):

add session_start() in the other page.

Comment: Ohhh makmesh, you started so well

Comment: This does not solve the problem with the SQL syntax.